# Livewire load javascript after event was fired and component was rerendered

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm having the problem when in my view I have a inline javascript that is being pushed to the stack in the layout. The problem here is that when my event is fired

```
 <button type="button" class="form-icon" wire:click="changeTrainingType">
     <i class="fa fa-exchange-alt"></i>
 </button>
```

the component is being rerendered and my javascript is not being executed (in the docs it says that the JS in executed only once) how do you handle that?

This is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Profile\Administration;

use Livewire\Component;

class CreateWorkoutsController extends Component
{
    public bool $weeklyTrainingType = false;
    protected $listeners = ['changeTrainingType'];

    public function changeTrainingType()
    {
        $this->weeklyTrainingType = !$this->weeklyTrainingType;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.profile.administration.workouts.create')
            ->extends('layouts.auth');
    }
}
```

And my JS

```
<script src="{{ url('js/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('libs/js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
    console.log('here');
    Livewire.on('changeTrainingType', event => {
        alert('A post was added with the id of: ');
    })
    flatpickr('#event-date', {
        enableTime: true,
        minDate: 'today',
        dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
        time_24hr: true,
    });

    flatpickr('.time-picker', {
        mode: 'multiple',
        enableTime: true,
        dateFormat: "w H:i",
        time_24hr: true
    });

    ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#description'))
        .then(editor => {
            editor.editing.view.change(writer => {
                writer.setStyle('height', '400px', editor.editing.view.document.getRoot())
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button it dispatches an event of type "method", once you're defining this like wire:click directive. In this case, you don't need the listener for it.
But if you wanna hook this method call, you can do this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    Livewire.hook('message.sent', (message,component) => {
       if (message.updateQueue[0].method === 'changeTrainingType') {
           alert('there was a call to this method');  
       }
    });
});
```

Otherwise, instead wire:click="name_method" use wire:click="$emit('name_of_event')" and use the listener property for hook it.

Comment: I did try with emiting, even selfEmit, since I'm listening in the same component for this event. The problem is that when the AJAX is fired and the components is reloaded the inline javascript is GONE. They  say it only renders once in the docs, but how do I stop the component from rerendering the JS so I can work with it after events :(